# Count all files in a directory including subdirectories file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sftp

Below is my script, but it is not working after connecting to the sftp.
Please  help me with this.

I am not getting any error. It is not getting into the loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT=`pwd`
File_Path=/appinfprd/bi/info/Client/Scripts/Test/
cd $File_Path
sftp STREAM@abc.sxm.com
for D in *;
do 
  echo $D;
  File_count=`find $D -type f| wc -l;`
  echo $File_Path$D '|' $File_count  >> File_count.txt
done
exit
```

Comment: You are invoking `sftp` in interactive mode, so it's waiting for you to type some commands. Once you manually exit `sftp`, the remainder of your script will be executed.

Comment: but before exit from sftp i want to count the no of files in all directories.How can  i modify  the script?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to the file path before connecting with sftp to the target machine itself .

```
File_Path=/appinfprd/bi/info/Client/Scripts/Test/
```

So where do you want to count the files actually . In the source System or in target ?

If you want to run a set of commands in remote machine and store the result there , store these commands into a batch file like commands.batch,and the run like below :

```
sftp -b commands.batch STREAM@abc.sxm.com
```

And for running with ssh ,as it will be a better way to execute the commands you mentioned above ,store the commands in to file script.sh and run like below .

```
ssh -o BatchMode=yes abc.sxm.com sh -s < "script.sh"
```

Comment: i want to count the no of files from sftp (Source System)

Comment: Sorry . If you want to count the number of files in local why you are going into SFTP . So I am guessing you want to connect to remote machine .Then need to go to the path    $File_Path . And then count the number of files in each subdirectory in this path there . is that right ?

Comment: Also I don't understand why we have to get this kind of requirement to done over sftp . If you want to implement something to get the number of files and all better done it with ssh itself .That will be easier I feels

Comment: Actually my clients will post files in sftp. i have to confirm that all the files have been posted. if not i have to alert customer.

Comment: @ Mathews Jose  i have modified my script like  #!/bin/bash 

URL=STREAM@xfer.sxm.com

TMPFILE=/appinfprd/bi/infogix/Client/Scripts/Test/File_count_sftp.txt
echo 'ls -1' > $TMPFILE

function handle_dir {
  echo "====== $1 ========="
  local dir=$1
  sftp -b $TMPFILE "$URL:$dir" | tail -n +2 | while read info; do
    echo "$info"
    if egrep -q '^d' <<< $info; then
       info=$(echo $info)
       subdir=$(cut -d ' ' -f9- <<< $info)
       handle_dir "$dir/$subdir"
    echo $1 '/' $subdir  >> $TMPFILE
    fi
  done
}

handle_dir "."    Now i can print path not no of files.

Comment: @Midhun yes ..I too saw the answer in the link added to the question . new info :)

Comment: ,Again for counting  the no of files we can use printf 'cd Inbound\nls\n' | sftp -b - user@host | wc -l  . But i dont understand where should i add this command.

Comment: I believe you can add the below lines before the call to  :  handle_dir "$dir/$subdir"                                      
#######################################
echo "cd $dir/$subdir ; wc -l " > tmpf
sftp -b tmpf  user@host   > tempresult
echo "Number of files is `cat tempresult`"
rm tmp tempresult                    Try once and let me know

Comment: Its not working. It is creating a files but does not have any data in it.

Comment: try like below : **`echo "ls -1 " > tmpf ; sftp -b tmpf user@host:$dir/$subdir > tempresult ;
echo "Number of files is \`cat tempresult\`" ;
rm tmp tempresult` **

Comment: Got created a tmp file with output of ls -l

Comment: Got the output by using this ---- var="$(printf "cd $dir/$subdir\nls\n" | sftp -b - $URL  | wc -l)" ------ Command.